# magento:get list of all available payment method

Tags: magento, payment-method

how can i get list of payment methods with detail like code,title,method and? is it possible get available payment method in store with API ? i need list of all available payment method in magento store.

Answer (score 9):

**Here You can get all available payment methods in Magento**

If for any reason you need to a get a list with all payment methods in Magento, you can do it easily by using the payment config class (`app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Config.php`).

**To get a list with all payments active and inactive:**

- `$allAvailablePaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getAllMethods();`

**To get a list with all active payment methods:**

- `$allActivePaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();`

**To get a list with all credit cards that Magento supports:**

- `$allCcTypes = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getCcTypes();`

Answer (score 4):

get active payment methods

```
$payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
$methods = array(array('value'=>'','label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('–Please Select–')));

foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
    $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
    $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
        'label'   => $paymentTitle,
        'value' => $paymentCode,
    );
}
return $methods;
```

Comment: i copy past this code in php file and add vardump $methods but it`s show no thing

Answer (score 2):

yes you can get payment method using api. here is your solution

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'cart_payment.list', 'quoteId');
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also this helper:

```
$methods = Mage::helper('payment)->getStoreMethods($store = null, $quote = null)
```

So you can check for a single store and for a quote if you need.